# Not able to get php parsed data in framework7 through ajax call

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, html-framework-7

```
function pendingorder(){

            app.request({
            type:"POST",
            url: "pages/getpeningorer.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success:function(data) {
                console.log(data);
             var result = $.parseJSON(data);
              $.each(result, function(key, value){
                $.each(value, function(k, v){
                    if(k === "order_id"){
                        $("#pendingtable >tbody:last").append(
                            $('<tr>').append(
                                $('<td>').append(v)
                                .append(
                                    $('</td>').append(
                                        $('</tr>')
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            );
                    }
                    if(k === "product_id"){
                        $("#demoTable >tbody >tr:last").append(

                            $('<td>').append(v)
                            .append(
                                $('</td>')

                                )

                            );
                    }

                    if(k === "status"){
                        $("#demoTable >tbody >tr:last").append(

                            $('<td>').append(v)
                            .append(
                                $('</td>')

                                )

                            );
                    }

                    if(k === "remark"){
                        $("#demoTable >tbody >tr:last").append(

                            $('<td>').append(v)
                            .append(
                                $('</td>')

                                )

                            );
                    }
                    if(k === "postingDate"){
                        $("#demoTable >tbody >tr:last").append(

                            $('<td>').append(v)
                            .append(
                                $('</td>')

                                )

                            );
                    }

                    });
            });
        console.log(data);}
    });
      console.log('execute success');   
}

 I AM trying to call ajax through function....But not working. In a similar way, I post data it is working.
```

PHP code:

enter code here

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
     die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
     $sql = "SELECT order_id,product_id,status,remark,postingDate FROM order_track_history where status='In process'";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
    $Pdata = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $picture = array(
    "order_id" => $row['order_id'],
    "product_id"         => $row['product_id'],
    "status"          => $row['status'],
    "remark"       => $row['remark'],
    "postingDate"       => $row['postingDate']
  );
  $Pdata[] = $picture;
}`enter code here`
    echo json_encode($Pdata);
```

Here I am sending my data to ajax calls in JSON format. But not able to see data at HTML page.

Comment: have you tried console.log the data return by your php script?

Comment: not getting data also in console

Comment: if you access this page `pages/getpeningorer.php` direct from browser, what is result will you got?

Comment: -- also make sure you are enable error in php.ini or set this code in your php file `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: work after setting  var result = $.parseJSON(data); to var result = data;

Answer (score 0):

it seems like there's something wrong with your php codes, try this code instead

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
foreach($row as $r) {
    $picture = array(
    "order_id" => $r['order_id'],
    "product_id"         => $r['product_id'],
    "status"          => $r['status'],
    "remark"       => $r['remark'],
    "postingDate"       => $r['postingDate']
    );
}
```